# Inducing a self-extension of a quotient module

Tags: ring-theory, modules

Let $R$ be an associative ring with $1$, but not necessarily commutative. Let $K$ be an $R$-module and $N$ be an $R$-submodule of $K$.

If $f: K \to K$ is an $R$-homomorphism such that $f(N) \subset N$ then $f$ induces an $R$-homomorphism $f^{\prime}: K/N \to K/N$.

Question: are there any nice conditions under which $g \in Ext^1_R(K,K)$ induces an element $g^{\prime} \in Ext^1_R(K/N,K/N)$?

Answer (score 1):

The short exact sequence $N \rightarrowtail K \twoheadrightarrow K/N$ gives rise to a short exact sequence $\Omega(N) \stackrel{\iota}{\rightarrowtail} \Omega(K) \oplus P\twoheadrightarrow \Omega(K/N)$, where $P$ is some projective module. The element $g\in\mathop{\rm Ext}^1(K,K)$ is represented by a map $g:\Omega(K)\oplus P \to K$.

Now, analogously to the $\mathop{\rm Hom}$-case, by the first isomorphism theorem:

> If $g(\iota(\Omega(N)))\subset N$, then $g$ induces a morphism $g':\Omega(K/N) \to K/N$, which represents an element $g'\in\mathop{\rm Ext}(K/N,K/N)$.

Comment: Thank you very much! Sorry, what is $\Omega$?

Comment: @IntegrableSystemsEnthusiast : $\Omega(M)$ denotes the syzygy, or Heller translate, of a module $M$: Given $M$, choose a surjective morphism $u: P\to M$, where $P$ is projective, and define $\Omega(M) = \ker(u)$.
(Normally, one assumes that $u$ is the projective cover of $M$, if that exists.)

Then $\mathop{\rm Ext}^1(M,N) = \mathop{\rm Hom}(\Omega(M),N)/ U$, where $U\subset \mathop{\rm Hom}(\Omega(M),N)$ is the set of all $u:\Omega(M)\to N$ that extend to a morphism $P\to N$.

Comment: @EricD Thank you very much! Sorry, do you know if by any chance $Ext^1(N,N)$ is the kernel of your map          $Ext^1(K,K)_{g(\iota(\Omega(N)) \subset N} \to Ext^1(K/N,K/N)$

Comment: @IntegrableSystemsEnthusiast
There is in general no natural way of viewing $\mathop{\rm Ext}^1(N,N)$ as a submodule of $\mathop{\rm Ext}^1(K,K)$ (or, $\mathop{\rm Hom}(N,N)$ as a submodule of $\mathop{\rm Hom}(K,K)$ for that matter), so it is not clear to me how that would work.

Think for example of the case when $K$ is projective. Then $\mathop{\rm Ext}^1(K,K)=0$, but certainly both $\mathop{\rm Ext}^1(N,N)$ and $\mathop{\rm Ext}^1(K/N,K/N)$ may be non-zero for a given, proper submodule $N\subset K$.